# mod_rewrite to edit cookies conditionally

Tags: mod-rewrite, cookie

Is it possible to use mod_rewrite to modify values in cookies based upon a condition? I am completely new to HTTP, but I have tried a thing or two. The only regex I know is Perl-style, I hope it is okay.

```
RewriteRule s/.[0-9][0-9][0-9]/COOKIE=MSFNODE/g;
```

1. `MSFNODE` is a value in my cookie.
2. The thing I want to run my regex on is `SESSIONID` (also in my cookie). I'm not sure how to choose that as a target.
3. As the regex shows, I want to replace `.[0-9][0-9][0-9]` with my cookie value called `MSFNODE`, *but only if `MSFNODE` exists!*

Is `COOKIE=MSFNODE` the right way to do this? Also, I only want this to happen if `MSFNODE` exists — as it is now, will it just pass on through and not follow the rewrite rule if `MSFNODE` doesn't exist?

I feel like even my most basic regex is flawed here.

Comment: You _could_ probably do this with mod_rewrite, but honestly, I suspect there are more appropriate tools for the job. It might help if you told us just what you want to accomplish with this.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen You can manually set the `Set-Cookie` header using mod_headers, but if you need to set this "conditionally", your options are limited unless you are on Apache 2.4 (expressions). mod_rewrite handles this just fine on all versions of Apache.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can Get/Detect/check for existance of cookie through [RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

Set Cookie value with the [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) flag [cookie|CO](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_co) which has this syntax:
`[CO=NAME:VALUE:DOMAIN:lifetime:path:secure:httponly]`

An example with them both together:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} cookiekey=cookievalue [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L,CO=cookiekey:NewCookieValue:mydomain.com:86400:/]
```

In the example above the redirection will only happen if cookiekey has a value of cookievalue. You can also use regex in the cookievalue RewriteCond if you desire.

More examples (read user comments as well):
http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess-fresh.html#Cookie_Manipulation_Tests_mod_rewrite

Comment: Looks like a typo... it should be `CO=` (not `CO:`) in your example (as you have stated in the _syntax_ just above it).